# Forwarding an X proccess via SSH automatically by a script

Tags: 16.04, scripts, ssh, xorg, conky

I've been trying to set up conky to monitor some basic stats (processor/memory usage, hdd usage etc) from my home server.

After a lot of messing around today I've managed to get the process to work by logging in via

```
screen ssh -X
```

and then running

```
conky -c /path/to/config
```

The conky process then starts up on my laptop and persists even when I close the ssh session down.

However I'm trying to get this to start from a script on my laptop so I can auto run it at boot.

I've set up a user who logs in via a key with no password to try to get it all working (eventually I aim to try to get it to simply ask for a password when I log in and the process starts) but I just can't get it to work.

The script I'm using is

```
#/bin/bash
screen ssh -X myconkyuser@myserverip "conky -c /path/to/config"
```

but it just refuses to display conky.

Even manually entering

```
screen ssh -X myconkyuser@myserverip "conky -c /path/to/config"
```

from a terminal won't do it.

If I do

```
screen ssh -X -vv myconkyuser@myserverip "conky -c /path/to/config"
```

I can see that the ssh connection is taking place and conky is starting up, it just isn't being passed to my laptop's x server correctly.

I've also tried putting the `conky -c /path/to/config`  as its own script on the server and using

```
screen ssh -X myconkyuser@myserverip "sh /path/to/conkystartupscript"
```

but the outcome is the same.

I'll attach the output from `-vv` to see if it can shed any light, I'm guessing the problem might be that the session is closing down before the conky process actually outputs to the display but I've tried adding a `pause 10` below the conky line to no avail.

Can anyone help?

```
will@will-Inspiron-7520 ~ 19:46:44 $ ssh -X -vv myconkyuser@myserverip "conky -c /path/to/myconky/config "
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /my/ssh/folder/config
debug1: /my/ssh/folder/config line 1: Applying options for myserverip
debug1: /my/ssh/folder/config line 8: Applying options for myserverip
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "myserverip" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to myserverip [myserverip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /my/ssh/folder/id_ed25519 type 4
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /my/ssh/folder/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /my/ssh/folder/myconkyuserid_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /my/ssh/folder/myconkyuserid_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to myserverip:22 as 'myconkyuser'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:yXsLEfcX1vuLtfzDI/flPwX4OYATC0Usa9EKmZFojWE
debug1: Host 'myserverip' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /my/ssh/folder/known_hosts:5
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /my/ssh/folder/myconkyuserid_rsa (0x5560479c2e00), explicit, agent
debug2: key: will@will-Inspiron-7520 (0x5560479c2ea0), agent
debug2: key: /my/ssh/folder/id_ed25519 (0x5560479b5060), explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /my/ssh/folder/myconkyuserid_rsa
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 279
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:PanRCck33pj+N8mNWoTLkaoaVudzUQlv5CTaF12SJ0Y
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to myserverip ([myserverip]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug2: callback start
debug2: x11_get_proto: /usr/bin/xauth  list :0 2>/dev/null
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug2: channel 0: request x11-req confirm 1
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_GB.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = 
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug1: Sending command: conky -c /path/to/myconky/config 
debug2: channel 0: request exec confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: X11 forwarding request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: exec request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 7
conky: debug2: channel 0: written 7 to efd 7
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 108
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 62
Syntax error (/path/to/myconky/config:2: unexpected symbol near '#') while reading config file. 
conky: Assuming it's in old syntax and attempting conversion.
debug2: channel 0: written 170 to efd 7
debug1: client_input_channel_open: ctype x11 rchan 3 win 65536 max 16384
debug1: client_request_x11: request from 127.0.0.1 36372
debug2: fd 8 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 1: new [x11]
debug1: confirm x11
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 65
conky: desktop window (1a00022) is subwindow of root window (d5)
debug2: channel 0: written 65 to efd 7
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 28
conky: window type - normal
debug2: channel 0: written 28 to efd 7
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 45
conky: drawing to created window (0x5200001)
debug2: channel 0: written 45 to efd 7
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 32
conky: drawing to double buffer
debug2: channel 0: written 32 to efd 7
debug2: channel 0: rcvd ext data 42
conky: forked to background, pid is 14055
debug2: channel 0: written 42 to efd 7
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eow
debug2: channel 0: close_read
debug2: channel 0: input open -> closed
debug2: channel 1: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 1: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 1: obuf empty
debug2: channel 1: close_write
debug2: channel 1: output drain -> closed
debug1: channel 1: FORCE input drain
debug2: channel 1: ibuf empty
debug2: channel 1: send eof
debug2: channel 1: input drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
debug2: channel 0: almost dead
debug2: channel 0: gc: notify user
debug2: channel 0: gc: user detached
debug2: channel 0: send close
debug2: channel 0: is dead
debug2: channel 0: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 2
debug2: channel 1: send close
debug2: channel 1: rcvd close
debug2: channel 1: is dead
debug2: channel 1: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 1: free: x11, nchannels 1
Transferred: sent 16740, received 12920 bytes, in 3.8 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 4378.2, received 3379.1
debug1: Exit status 0
```

There are a few syntax errors in the conky file (it's a very old one but it does the job I want) but I don't think they're causing the problem as if I `ssh -X` into the server and then start conky everything works as desired.

(NB the code output above is WITHOUT using screen as using screen clears the terminal. It looks like it's going through essentially the same process though)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I seem to have solved this. It does seem to have been an issue with the connection shutting down before the x process could be forwarded.  I also found that the 'screen' command wouldn't work from a script run from outside a terminal.

My new script is

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 25 && (to ensure my desktop gets a chance to boot before running)
conky -c ~/.conky/.conkynewrc && (my local conky session)
ssh -X willconky@myserverip "conky -c /home/willconky/.conky/.conkynewrc && sleep 10" & (my remote conky session)
```

This all appears to now be working ok.